# Python Dictionary

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, amazon-rds

I am getting the output from my previous executions something like this:

```
[{u'Value': '2018-06-21', u'Key': 'Deletion_Date'}]
```

I want to get only 2018-06-21 saved in a variable.

I tried this

```
deletion_date = response1['TagList'][0]['Value']
```

But I am getting error

```
deletion_date = response1['TagList'][0]['Value']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could someone help me with this or some alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing how the response example you shown relates to `response1` (there is no `'TagList'` in your example). It looks like `response1['TagList']` is an empty list.

Otherwise you're on the right track (you can always check your exact case directly in the python shell):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul 01 2016, 15:36:53) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> response = [{u'Value': '2018-06-21', u'Key': 'Deletion_Date'}]
>>> response[0]
{u'Key': 'Deletion_Date', u'Value': '2018-06-21'}
>>> response[0]['Value']
'2018-06-21'
```